# usage of modelattribute in form tag of jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

Generally i use @modelattribute annotation to bind form values to bean in the following procedure.

in jsp

```
<form:form commandname="test" ../>
```

in java class

```
@modelattribute("test")
public Test commandobject()
{
return new test();
}
```

recently i came across a snippet where in they are using modelattribute in place of commandname in jsp and they are not creating any method for creating object.whether all this will take care by framework due to change annotation? please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

When you put `@ModelAttribute` on a method, as in your example, it indicates to Spring that if that class does not exist in the Model it should create one and put it there. It allows you to have default values in your Model Object. If you couple that with the `@SessionAttributes` annotation on the Controller, it will extend this feature to ensure that the object will be put in Session as soon as the controller is hit.

The attributes `commandName` and `modelAttribute` on the `form:form` tag do primarily the same thing, which is to map the form's fields to an Object of some type in the Controller.  I believe `modelAttribute` is the preferred method, and `commandName` is only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: it indicates to Spring that if that class does not exist in the Model it should create one and put it there??   can u explain this statement clearly

Comment: The ModelAttribute annotation, to quote the JavaDoc, used to "[bind] a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view."  It can be used on a Parameter to a Controller's handler method, or on a method that takes no arguments but returns an instance of said Model Attribute value.  An example can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/